# Android. I want to add action to add action to main.xml button

Tags: android, button, action, android-actionbar, onclicklistener

I want to add action to add action to main.xml button.

here is my code:

`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/SendMes"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textColorHighlight="#ff0000"
    android:textColorHint="#ff0000"
    android:textColorLink="#ff0000"
    android:enabled="True"
    android:title="Pargi"/>
```

Just how to start something like onclicklistner?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onOptionsItemSelected` method in your activity in order to trap the selected item's click event:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   //get the item id, match with required one and do your stuff

}
```

Make sure you inject your menu xml file too:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_whatever_menu_file, menu);
    return true;
}
```

For more info, read [this](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-menus-part-1-options-menu/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onOptionsItemSelected` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.SendMes:
    //Do whatever you want
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have u tried adding>> android:onClick="YOUR_METHOD_IN_ACTIVITY" ?